# Rotational Average

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory

Given an input integer `n >= 10`, output the average of all deduplicated rotations of the integer.

For example, for input `123`, the rotations are `123` (no rotation), `231` (one rotation) and `312` (two rotations). The average of those is `(123 + 231 + 312) / 3` or `222`.

As another example, take `4928`. The rotations are `4928`, `9284`, `2849`, and `8492`. Taking the average of those four numbers equals `6388.25`.

For another example, for input `445445`, the deduplicated rotations are `445445`, `454454`, and `544544`, so the output is `481481`.

For input `777`, there is only one deduplicated rotation, so the output is `777`.

### Rules

- If applicable, you can assume that the input/output will fit in your language's native Integer type.
- The input and output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Can we take input as a list of digits?

Comment: @Dennis Sure, that's fine. Go save some bytes. :p

Comment: Do you have an example where the deduplication actually changes the output ? In your 445445 example, each 3 unique rotation happens twice, so leaving them doesn't change the output.

Comment: @Kaldo No, I wasn't able to (manually) come up with one, but that doesn't mean one doesn't exist, so I left the deduplication rules in place.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork So we every answer should deduplicate rotations even though if they validate the examples without it ?

Comment: @Kaldo Let **d** be the number of digits of **n** and **k** the smallest positive integer such that rotating **n** **k** digits to the left reproduces **n**. Take **q** and **0 ≤ r < k** such that **d = qk + r**. Rotating **n** both **d** and **qk** digits to the left must yield **n**, so **r = 0**. This means each unique rotation occurs **q** times, so deduplicating the rotations isn't needed to compute the average.

Comment: @Dennis lagrange theorem ^^

Comment: Taking input as a list of digits contradicts "If applicable, you can assume that the input/output will fit in your language's native Integer type.", right?

Comment: @RK. Well, the *output* won't fit anyway, since it usually isn't integer.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>38</s> 36 bytes

```python
lambda*n:10**len(n)//9*sum(n)/len(n)
```

Takes the digits as separate arguments. *Thanks to @Rod for suggesting Python 3, saving 2 bytes.*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRK8/K0EBLKyc1TyNPU1/fUqu4NBfEggj8T8svUshTyMxTMDQy1lEwsTSyAJImpkCko2Bubm7FxVlQlJlXopGmXp1nZVaroGunUJ2moZWbWKABFNZRKC4pAhqjqWllUauu@R8A)

Comment: An additional byte could be saved by switching back to Python 2 and taking an array of floats.

Comment: You don't need to take the digits as separate arguments, [a regular old list does just fine](https://tio.run/##JYzNCsIwHMPP@hS5rSuVuQ/tVtAn8VLRYmH9r7T1IGPPXiuGEH4kEP9Jr4X6bHDBLc/a3R8apNoj5/OTGNVNM/H4dj/6F9ksAQRLaLteYJi6seRwKhaQUqr9zgdLiZlqJXXecLhiNWy2MTGnPSuTQEyhXBWpcavq/AU)

Answer (score 9):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 bytes

```apl
10⊥≢⍴+/÷≢
```

A monadic function taking a vector of digits as an argument.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wRDg0ddSx91LnrUu0Vb//B2IOv//3SgeHWaAkSqd/Gh9YaPuoAKttYqPOqdq@Ccn1eWWlRSrFCSr5CokJNZXKKQn6aQkpmeCRRLyywC8tPyixRSE4tTQRKlxalc6QqGRsZA0sTSyAJEmZgCEZBhbm4OAA)

I take the average of the digits `+/÷≢`, then repeat it by the length of the input `≢⍴`, and finally convert from base 10.

Conceptially, I am taking the sum of the rotations (without carrying):

```apl
 4  2  9  8
 2  9  8  4
 9  8  4  2
+8  4  2  9
 -----------
 23 23 23 23
```

This is just `4+2+9+8` repeated 4 times. Then converting from base `10` (which does the carrying for me)
 and dividing by the length. Although I divide by the length earlier on because it is equivilent and saves bytes.

Comment: That's genial :D

Comment: @Leo FWIW the answers that multiply the average by a rep digit are doing essentially the same thing

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>84</s> <s>73</s> 64 bytes

```r
function(D,K=sum(D|1))mean(array(D,K+1:0)[1:K,1:K]%*%10^(K:1-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T8NFx9u2uDRXw6XGUFMzNzUxTyOxqCixEiSubWhloBltaOWtA8SxqlqqhgZxGt5WhrpAlf/TNJI1zHWAUFOTC8Q20bHUMdKxAMoAAA)

Input as list of digits.

Thanks to MickyT for shaving off 11 bytes! 8 bytes shaved by Dennis' proof that deduplication is unnecessary.

Comment: With a slightly different way to rotate the number [for 73](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T8NFx9u2uDRXw6XGUFMzNzUxT6M0L7OwNFUjN7GkKLMCJK9tqOOtGW1o5a0DxLGqWqqGBnEa3laGukAdmv/TNJI1zHWAUFOTC8Q20bHUMdKxAMoAAA)

Comment: @MickyT aaahhh clever use of recycling!

Comment: @MickyT `array(D,K+1:0)` is shorter than `matrix(D,K+1,K)` by a byte.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 10, <s>163</s> <s>137</s> <s>76</s> <s>72</s> 71 bytes

```java
n->(Math.pow(10,n.size())-1)/9*n.stream().mapToInt(i->i).sum()/n.size()
```

-36 bytes thanks to *@Nevay*.
-61 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire* by creating a port of [*@Dennis*' Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162438/52210).
-1 bytes by taking the input as a List of digits instead of String.

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##tY9NT8MwDIbv@xU@JijNKAzBVKjEEYntMm6Ig2mzLaVNqsTdNFB/ezH7uCCOIx@W7Lx@8rrCDSZV@TEUNcYIM7TuawRgHZmwxMLA/CcFKH33XhsoRMUNuiNb68cQcPdsI90/sXplQg5OZqzu@fKJhGQLmIODBxhckosZ0lq3fivSS@V0tJ9GSJmkcjy94JSCwUZI3WD74hkpbJJbqWPHxfFJPmQHeMt2GH78Y@NtCQ17FwsK1q1e31AefC92kUyjfUe65ReqnXC6EM5s4Y9Jfk8XNcZ9PVVX6lryys5Jnagpc@/@gTtRN2ofz86@VbxP1H7UD98)

```java
n->                                 // Method with String parameter and double return-type
  (Math.pow(10,n.size())-1)/9       //  Repunits the same length as the input-size
  *n.stream().mapToInt(i->i).sum()  //  multiplied by the sum of digits
  /n.size()                         //  divided by the input-size
```

Comment: 151 bytes: `n->{var s=new java.util.HashSet();var r=0d;for(int l=n.length(),x;l-->0;)if(s.add(x=new Integer(n=n.substring(1)+n.charAt(0))))r+=x;return r/s.size();}`, stream approach with 137 bytes: `n->java.util.stream.IntStream.range(0,n.length()).map(i->new Integer(n.substring(i)+n.substring(0,i))).distinct().average().getAsDouble()`

Comment: Use `orElse(0)` instead of `getAsDouble()`.

Comment: [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##hY7NbsJADITvPIXFabdqlp8GBRTBG8CFY8XB3SxkIXGirEOpqjx7cEukniqk8cH2p5k54xWjc3bpbYEhwBY9fY8APLFrjmgd7H5WgKxqPwoHVu258XQC0qncOxlRYGRvYQcEa@gp2myRc1NXn2o2fSVTODpxrrSerF7I2ByboLQpsVa3aHOL4qU2oS2VnvyhaZ8@rGuJFesh4Vr5DErpONR4P6B@9Nt/BXalqVo2tXy4ICVRajybv431b9f/mXg1Xz6H4oXoKZYkycB0o66/Aw), based on others' solution. Round using `(int)` for 5 mote bytes, if needed.

Comment: You don't need to cast as a double: `Math.pow` already takes care of that. That'll spare you 3 bytes.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire It will give incorrect results if I do that. The cast to int is used so we can **integer**-divide by 9 and multiply by the sum of digits. Only then it should a double to get the average. If I remove both `(int)` and `*.1` it will for example output `6388.888...` instead of `6388.25` for the input `4928`. And if I cast the entire thing or just the `.pow` to an `int` instead, it will output `6388`.

Comment: My bad: I was not thinking about the expected decimal values.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ok, I was overthinking it. The `10^length/9` in Dennis' answer is used to calculate repunits, which is basically `(10^length-1)/9`. So the cast to int or `*1.` is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
d´MKA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fm/@oqTHlf8qhLb7ejv///482NDLWMbE0stAxNTEBIh1zc/NYAA)

#### Explanation

```
d´MKA
    A  Take the average of the digits
 ´MK   Replace each element of the original list with the average
d      Join the list to get a number
```

---

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
A§modṙŀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fm/@oqTHlv@Oh5bn5KQ93zjza8P///2hDI2MdE0sjCx1TExMg0jE3N48FAA)

#### Explanation

```
A§modṙŀ
      ŀ  Take the range [1..length(input)]
 §m  ṙ   Rotate the input by each element of the range
   od    Convert each list of digits to a number
A        Take the average of the list
```

Comment: For a puzzle, there is at least one `5` byte solution

Comment: @H.PWiz I can't figure it out, could you give out a hint? :P

Comment: @Leo There is no `ṙ` or `ŀ`, and the first character (on the left) is not `A`

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
Ṗ⌊ṁ
```

*-2 bytes thanks to @lyxal*

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuaAiLCIiLCLhuZbijIrhuYEiLCIiLCIxMjMiXQ==)

Explanation

```
Ṗ   # Permutations
 ⌊  # Convert each to an integer
  ṁ # Mean
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuZbhuYXijIrhuYEiLCIiLCI0NDU0NDUiXQ==) for 4 bytes, because `ṅ` vectorises when there's sublists

Comment: @Lyxal Oh yeah I just realised that a few days ago, thanks

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuaAiLCIiLCLhuZbijIrhuYEiLCIiLCIxMjMiXQ==) for 3 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
ṙJḌÆm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzpleD3f0HG7L/X90j8vhdpVHTWvc//83NDLWUTCxNLIAkiamQKSjYG5uDgA)

#### How it works

```
ṙJḌÆm  Main link. Argument: A (digit array)

 J     Yield the indices of A, i.e., [1, ..., len(A)].
ṙ      Rotate A 1, ..., and len(A) units to the left, yielding a 2D array.
  Ḍ    Convert each rotation from decimal to integer.
   Æm  Take the arithmetic mean.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
vÀD}\OIg/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/7HCDS22Mv2e6/v//JiamQAQA)

Comment: `v` with no `y`, interesting.

Comment: `gFÀD})¨Osg/` was where I was thinking.

Comment: Do you know how to use the `.æ  = pop a      compute permutations by function, usage: .æ<FUNC>}` command yet? I don't either, but it seems fit to this.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn v without y is the shortest solution I could find to perform the rotation g(input) times.
I'm checking the .æ, doesn't seem like it's registering <FUNC>}

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ñJä⌠╤►
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=a44a84f4d110&i=%22123%22%0A%224928%22%0A%22445445%22%0A%22777%22&a=1&m=2)

This program takes a quote-delimited string as input, and expresses the average as a reduced fraction. e.g. `777/1`  It's not necessary to de-duplicate the rotations.  It never changes the result.

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
:)  get all character rotations
{em convert strings back to integers
:V  mean - integer inputs means result will be rational
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%3A%29%09get+all+character+rotations%0A%7Bem%09convert+strings+back+to+integers%0A%3AV%09mean+-+integer+inputs+means+result+will+be+rational&i=%22123%22%0A%224928%22%0A%22445445%22%0A%22777%22&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-lpF`, <s>24</s> 22 bytes

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -lpF
$_=1x@F/s/./+$&/g*eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tawwsFNv1hfT19bRU0/XSu1LDHn/39DI2MuE0sjCy4TE1Mg4jI3N@f6l19QkpmfV/xfN6fA7b@ur6meoYGeAQA)

Doing it as a list of digits is only 1 byte shorter and feels like cheating:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$;+=$_}{$_=1x$./$.*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/FWttWJb62WiXe1rBCRU9fRU9L5f9/Ey4TLlMuMPkvv6AkMz@v@L9uwX9dX1M9QwM9AwA)

Comment: what's `usrt`? :P

Comment: @ASCII-only Wait,you don't have your executables in the `/usrt` directory ? Anyways, fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 15 bytes

```perl6
{.sum/$_*1 x$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoFZk@79ar7g0V18lXstQoUIlvva/NVdxIkhGQ8nQyFhJLzk/N0nPJ7O4RPM/AA)

The average is the digit average applied to each decimal position, so digit average times 111.... `1 x $_` produces a string of 1s which get coerced to strings by the multiply.

Takes a list of digits as input. A sequence would require a .cache before the sum, and a number or string input would need a .comb.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 60 bytes

```ruby
->n{a=b=c=0.0;a,b,c,n=a+n%10,b*10+1,c+1,n/10while n>0;a*b/c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCsIwEEDRq2Tjph3bmRpJRaYXCVlkgkVBhyKIkbZnj4H/dv/9kV@ZuRwnXSMLJ8YOrxEEEijHVg@EIA1hS5Aq7Qm/98fzZnSqXyN92oun4QT2Moxg7bkGzrnQveKybnlbjM9gZp9D2Msf)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 22 bytes

```
FromDigits[0#+Mean@#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zgq/DfrSg/1yUzPbOkONpAWds3NTHPQTlW7X9AUWZeSbSyjoKSgq6dgpKOQlq0cmysgpqCvoNCdbWhjpGOca2OQrWJjiWQaQFhmuiY6oBJENdcBwhra/8DAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 33 bytes

```ruby
->n{10**(k=n.size)/9*n.sum*1.0/k}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6v2tBAS0sj2zZPrzizKlVT31ILyCrN1TLUM9DPrv1foJAWHW2oY6RjHBvLBeaY6FgCuRYIromOqQ6YhAmZ6wBhbOx/AA)

A port of [Dennis's Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162438/77598)

#### Here's my lame attempt (74 bytes)

```ruby
->s{a=(1..s.size).map{|i|s.chars.rotate(i).join.to_i}|[];a.sum*1.0/a.size}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664OtFWw1BPr1ivOLMqVVMvN7GguiazplgvOSOxqFivKL8ksSRVI1NTLys/M0@vJD8@s7YmOtY6Ua@4NFfLUM9APxGssfZ/gUJatJKhkbFSLBeYaWJpZAFnm5gCEYxnbm6uFPsfAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 43 bytes

```javascript
x=>eval(x.join`+`)*'1'.repeat(n=x.length)/n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQ46hFi6KPQuwiESi1SpEtSsLb23vBfe7dHn@nhnjHcpiSzYyfi3IBgLxCYE@2tqoSnYAHb3RJkskQkc50qZaK3phejgiRT3lIMUz9KJTS5Qc)

> Can we take input as a list of digits? – Dennis♦ 7 mins ago
>
> @Dennis Sure, that's fine. Go save some bytes. :p – AdmBorkBork 3 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 bytes

Takes input as an array of single digit strings.

```
xpUÊ)÷UÊ
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=eHBVyin3Vco=&input=WyI0IiwiNCIsIjUiLCI0IiwiNCIsIjUiXQ==)

---

### Explanation

```
             :Implicit input of array U
 pUÊ         :Repeat each string length of U times
x   )        :Reduce by addition
     ÷UÊ     :Divide by the length of U
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>83</s> 77 bytes

```
def f(a):b={int(`a`[i:]+`a`[:i])for i in range(len(`a`))};print sum(b)/len(b)
```

EDIT: -6 bytes thanks to @ovs

Comment: [35, Dennis' solution](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSvPytBASysnNU8jT1PfUqu4NBfEgPD/FxRl5pUopGmY6OlY6ukY6elY6Gn@BwA), [38, not Dennis' solution](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSvRKjOvREPJUEkrJzVPI1FTU6u4NBdI60O4/wuKgPIKaRomejqWOkY6Fpr/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>21</s> 14 bytes<sup>[SBCS](http://github.com/abrudz/sbcs)</sup>

```apl
+/≢÷⍨⍳∘≢(⍎⌽)¨⊂
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wRt/Uediw5vf9S74lHv5kcdM4A8jUe9fY969moeWvGoqwmo6tAKdUMjY3UFdRNLIwsQZWIKRECGubm5OgA)

Tacit prefix function. Takes input as a string.

Thanks to Adám for [an enlightening 7 byte save](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44041397#44041397).

#### How?

```apl
+/≢÷⍨⍳∘≢(⍎⌽)¨⊂ ⍝ Main fn, example argument '123'
              ⊂ ⍝ Enclose the argument (turns it into a scalar)
             ¨  ⍝ Use each of the left arguments to
         ( ⌽)   ⍝ Rotate, then
          ⍎     ⍝ Convert strings into numbers
      ⍳∘≢       ⍝ Tally (≢) the argument, then index (⍳) from 1. 
                ⍝ Returns 1 2 3 for a 3 digit argument, and rotates the argument 1, 2, then 3 times.
     ⍨          ⍝ Use the result as left argument for
    ÷           ⍝ Divide
   ≢            ⍝ By the number of rotations
+/              ⍝ And sum the results
```

Comment: :| still can't get used to APL comments

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
Ｉ∕×ΣθＩ⭆θ1Ｌθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwyWzLDMlVSMkMze1WCO4NFejUFNHASwTXAJUle6bWKBRqKOgZKikqQmU8UnNSy/JACrS1LT@/9/E0sjiv25ZDgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    θ  θ  θ Input as a string
   Σ        Sum of digits
      ⭆ 1   Replace each character with the literal `1`
     Ｉ      Cast to integer
  ×         Multiply
         Ｌ  Length
 ∕          Divide
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 10 bytes

```
10#.#$+/%#
```

This is a port of H.PWiz's great APL solution to J.

Takes a list of digits as an argument.

### Explanation:

`+/%#` the average of the digits (divide `%` the sum of the digits `+/` by their  number `#`)

`#$`creates a list of copies of the average according to the number of digits

`10#.` convert form base 10

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DQ2U9ZRVtPVVlf9rcilwpSZn5CukKZgAoSmEhAkZKhgpGCPkLYFcCxjXHAT/AwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 34 bytes

Takes input as a list of digits.

```
n->fromdigits([vecsum(n)|x<-n])/#n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P1y6tKD83JTM9s6RYI7osNbm4NFcjT7OmwkY3L1ZTXznvf2JBQU6lRp6Crp1CQVFmXgmQqQTiKCmkARVq6ihERxvqGOkYxwJZJjqWQKYFhGmiY6oDJkFccx0gjI3V/A8A)

Answer (score 1):

### C++, <s>218</s> 208 bytes

-10 bytes thanks to Zacharý

```cpp
#include<set>
#include<cmath>
float a(int m){std::set<int>a;int n=m,t,c=0;for(;n>0;n/=10)++c;for(;n<c;++n){a.insert(m);t=m%10;m=m/10+std::pow(10.f,c-1)*t;}int s=0;for(int v:a){s+=v;}return float(s)/a.size();}
```

And, to test :

```cpp
int main() {
    printf("%f\n%f\n%f\n%f\n",a(123),a(4928),a(445445),a(777));
}
```

Comment: You don't need spaces between `#include` and `<`, and you can remove the `{}` around both `++c;` and `s+=v;`. You might be able to move the `int s=0` to the beginning with your other variables.

Comment: Also, I don't think you need the `n=0` in the second for loop, as it should have reached `0` by then. `m/=10;m+=std::pow(10.f,c-1)*t;` => `m=m/10+std::pow(10.f,c-1)*t`. And wouldn't using `int` instead of `auto` work?

Comment: You can still move `int s=0;` with your other variables, and do you need the braces around the `s+=v;`?

Comment: [168 bytes](https://tio.run/##TU5ta8IwEP7eXxEcQm6tmjhHtTH9JftyxFQDTVKSqKDoX@@yDtyOO557Xg5ODcPiqNT4Zpzqzwe9Nz6moNG2f1LUqS1eTFlMp7boeo@JIDUuEQv3mA5Nk4P7zFsUv26UTHQ@TBkle3/kjFqonHwq4cpSWGlXnJV2ztn74K@Us0oB4NK4qEPK0df1pUGIpbyIoNM5OBJXuIzmpimIxzi9gMZRIPeC5BpCljo6m3df7v/MKqR8/QEZNrv1dsLNZ@6fra5rAFE8xm8 "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: `n>0` => `n` might work.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
œÅA
```

Port of [*@tybocopperkettle*'s Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252104/52210), so make sure to upvote him/her as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6OTDrY7//xsaGQMA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/o5MPtzr@1/kfbWhkrGNiaWShY2JiCkQ65ubmsQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
œ    # Get all permutations of the (implicit) input
     #  e.g. 123 → ["123","132","213","231","312","321"]
 ÅA  # Take the average of this list
     #  → 222.0
     # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `E`, \$ 9 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 7.41 bytes

```
DLzP.ZDAA
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSq1LsgqWlJWm6FitdfKoC9KJcHB0hfKjwgiUmlkYWEDYA)

Port of Vyxal.

##### Explanation

```python
DLzP.ZDAA  # Implicit input. The E flag keeps it as a string.
DL         # Duplicate and get the length of the input string.
  zP       # Permutations of the input with the same length.
    .ZD    # Converted to integers from lists of characters.
       AA  # Get the average of this list of integers.
           # Implicit output.
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 10 bytes

```
mean(Ans)int(1/9₁₀^(dim(Ans
```

Takes input in `Ans` as a list. Port of [Dennis's Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162438/52210).

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

```
csms.<zdlzlz
```

Probably improvable.

```
c         lz     Divide by the length of the input:
 s               Reduce by +
  m     lz       Map over d = [0 ... the length of the input]:
   s.<zd         Shift the input d characters to the left and cast to int
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=csms.%3Czdlzlz&input=123&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=123%0A4928%0A445445%0A777&debug=0)

Comment: There's a built-in average function `o`.  If you do that and do I/O as lists of digits, you can get it down to [8 bytes](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m.O.%3CQdl&input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%5D%0A%5B4%2C+9%2C+2%2C+8%5D%0A%5B4%2C+4%2C+5%2C+4%2C+4%2C+5%5D%0A%5B7%2C+7%2C+7%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%5D%0A%5B4%2C+9%2C+2%2C+8%5D%0A%5B4%2C+4%2C+5%2C+4%2C+4%2C+5%5D%0A%5B7%2C+7%2C+7%5D&debug=0).

Comment: Ah, I was taking "If applicable, you can assume that the input/output will fit in your language's native Integer type." to mean that it had to be an integer if taken in as `Q`.

Answer (score 0):

## J, 23 Bytes

```
(+/%#)".~.(|."0 1~i.@#)
```

Takes input as a string

#### Explanation

```
          (|."0 1~i.@#)  | All rotations
        ~.               | Deduplicate
      ".                 | Convert each to int
(+/%#)                   | Average
```

Answer (score 0):

## Matlab, 65 bytes

```
c=num2str(n);l=nnz(c);mean(str2num(c(mod((1:l)+(0:l-1)'-1,l)+1)))
```

Gonna work on this, pretty sure it can be done better.

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 139 bytes

```
#(let[n(count %)G(set(apply map list(for[i(range n)](take n(drop i(cycle %))))))](/(apply +(for[g G](read-string(apply str g))))(count G)))
```

Quite sub-optimal language features for converting sequences of characters to integers.

Answer (score 0):

## dc, 37 bytes

This is a full program, reading input and printing the output:

```sed
?1sd[O~rzsadO<x+ldO*1+sd]dsxxOkld*la/p
```

It works by separating the number into its digits, and multiplying the mean of the digits by the appropriate length repdigit (which is built up in `d` as we go).

```sed
?                               # read input
 1sd                            # initialize d=1
    [                   ]dsxx   # define and execute recursive macro x:
     O~r                        #   remainder and quotient of /10
        zsa                     #   a = number of digits
           dO<x                 #   recurse if needed
               +ldO*1+sd        #   increment repdigit d
                             Ok         # after executing x, set precision 
                               ld*la/   # multiply by repdigit; divide by a
                                     p  # print the result
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 45 bytes

```powershell
($args-join'+'|iex)*("1"*($l=$args.Count))/$l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5RT4MwFIXf@RU3TXWwFQyMCT6QsBB91cjejFkqdoOFUWwhzmz8diywMW1u@vCdc889Jf9mQqYsz82EC9biTXBsdUzFVpo7nhWT2eSUsYMx1ZGNpjrOg16zIl4XlWHc4bxtNC3UNVCPhLrtzAk4jmNcgPvg@ATu575vOYsrdRdqCLi@rWbEnucRUJ@hGXCCJy4eaZKazx87llRw7F24pILuCWB2KBVlnxAAXv@RljKuRFZsFUcDQdaKRykVSyHoj94l38ARZgivETTDpmCyziu1cos3EP7L6Q1vL3FUy4rvhy7v4VCme3GdJEzKrsY5xWRf13qjD62YrCCikqHO298YxdfL/XNGLzRa0/4C)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 7 bytes

```
ĐŁᴇ₉⇹µ*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yISjjQ@3tD9q6nzUvvPQVq3//6NNdCx1jHQsYgE)

Takes the number as a list of digits

```
    Đ          implicit input (n); Đuplicate on stack
     Ł         get Łength (l)
      ᴇ₉       get repunit of length l 
        ⇹µ     get mean of digits of n
          *    multiply; implicit print
```